# Auto Login after Registeration PHP

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have a problem in auto login to my-account page after registration. Please help, here is my code. I am trying to login user without any email confirmation.

```
 <?php
    @ob_start();session_start();

    if($_SESSION['LOGIN_ID'] > 0)
    header("location:myaccount.php");   

    $invalidcaptcha = 0;
    if($_POST['register_submit'])
    {

        $ip = getIP();      
        $emailid = $_POST['emailid'];
        $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
        $confirm = '1';
        $blocked = '0';
        $ccode = base64_encode($email);

        $ures = mysql_query("select id from user where emailid='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['emailid'])."'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($ures) > 0 )
        {
            header("location:login.php?emailexist=1");  
        }
        else if($_POST['security_code']==$_SESSION['freecap_word_hash']) 
        {       
            mysql_query("insert into user set emailid='".mysql_real_escape_string($emailid)."',pwd='".md5($pwd)."',blocked='".$blocked."',confirm='".$confirm."',ccode='".$ccode."',reg_date=now(),reg_ip='".$ip."'");
            $i_id = mysql_insert_id();

             $res=mysql_query("SELECT id, emailid, pwd FROM users WHERE emailid='$emailid'");
       $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
       $count = mysql_num_rows($res); // if uname/pass correct it returns must be 1 row

        $_SESSION['LOGIN_ID'] = $row['userId'];
        header("Location: myaccount.php");

        }

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: other than your gaping wide open [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability, exactly **HOW** is this code not working?

Comment: so you want us to go over your entire code and debug it/test it, right? Not to mention the missing HTML for this. Plus, relevance to "jquery" is what?

Comment: `$row['userId']` = `$i_id` no need to use second select query

Comment: SELECT id, emailid,pwd where is userid in this?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `userid` here

```
$_SESSION['LOGIN_ID'] = $row['userId'];
```

And not using userId column in SELECT QUERY.

Other than to this issue, $i_id is equal to $row["userId"] than no need to use second SELECT QUERY.

In your case you just need to add userId column in this query:

```
SELECT id, emailid, pwd, userId FROM
```

But this query is extra as I mentioned.

This is another special point, stop using mysql_* its deprecated and closed in PHP 7, you can use mysqli_* or PDO.

It's better to use prepared statement, this will save your code with SQL Injection.

Comment: can u plz post exact line, it will be great help

Comment: @rajat-gupta u need to add userId column in your query but this query is extra